# How to fetch last record in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm working on a golang application in which I need to fetch last record from the table so I'm not able to do it. I have models mention below:-

```
type SQLTransaction struct {
    Id            int                       `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Version       uint64                    `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=version,proto3" json:"version,omitempty" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Hash          string                    `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=hash,proto3" json:"hash,omitempty"`
    VmStatusId    int                       `protobuf:"bytes,6,opt,name=vm_status_id,proto3" json:"vm_status_id,omitempty"`
}
```

Here is my gorm function in which I want to fetch the last record

```
func (mgr *manager) GetLastTxn() (int, error) {
    var versionId int
    resp := mgr.connection.Table("transactions").Last("", "version")
    return versionId, resp.Error
}
```

Error:-

```
model value required
[0.053ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE version ORDER BY `transactions`. DESC LIMIT 1
0 model value required
```

How can I achieve it please any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `versionId` represent, the transaction's `id` or the `version`? Which of those two are you trying to return? Or do you want both? And what do you mean by "last"? The greatest `id`? Or the greatest `version`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your example that should be handled.

First, the error `model value required` suggests that the `Last` method needs a model to store the result. If you want the entire record with all the data you can do it like this:

```
var lastVersion SQLTransaction
resp := mgr.connection.Table("transactions").Last(&lastVersion)
```

If you only want the ID of the record, you do something like this:

```
var lastVersion struct {
    ID int
}
resp := mgr.connection.Table("transactions").Last(&lastVersion)
```

Next, you don't need `Last("", "version")` because it doesn't do what you think it does. The first parameter is a pointer to your resulting object (which for all `go-gorm` methods always should be an object or a slice). The second one is a condition for the WHERE clause. So the correct syntax, if you don't need an additional WHERE clause, is:

```
resp := mgr.connection.Table("transactions").Last(&lastVersion)
```

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/26dd4c980a62d47c990a05da9e5566bff3b2b00c/finisher_api.go#L146) of the `Last` method, it considers the primary key when it executes the method, so you don't even need any additional parameters or conditions.